# Children's Novel, Early 2000's, Talking Tattoos

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I can't remember terribly much about the book. I think it was fairly large for a child.

The main character is a teenage girl. She is part of a family/clan who all have very specific superpowers. They range in intensity and specificity, but hers was on the low end. Tattoos could speak to her, and could tell her the inner thoughts of the person to whom they were attached. This worked even with temporary tattoos and ink drawn on skin.

I remember a minor subplot of her dealing with her attraction to a boy that gets drawn into whatever the major conflict is, but has no powers (wrong place/wrong time deal).

The major source of transportation is a yellow ex-school bus that is a main feature of the family. It also appears on the cover.

Comment: Neat idea! It reminds me of [Dragonmarks](http://eberron.wikia.com/wiki/Dragonmarks) in the Eberron universe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Savvy

This is *Savvy*, by Ingrid Law.

[image]

Yes, school bus on the cover.

And the main character has a family with various powers, such as her brother, who can create storms, or her mother, who does mundane tasks (anything from baking a cake to throwing or not throwing a horseshoe) perfectly.

You've got the tattoo power right:

> I couldn’t fathom how Bobbi had managed to get a tattoo. I knew that
> if Miss Rosemary, the woman with direct connections to heaven and the
> ability to get God Almighty to help her plan my birthday party, if she
> ever found out, Bobbi might not make it to her own next  birthday
> party, nor up to heaven to get her very own halo either.
>
> That was when that little angel turned its head, twirled its tail,
> and said, “She’s really very lonely you know …
>
> <sub>*Savvy*</sub>

There are at least two sequels, *Scumble* and *Switch*, I believe.